# file path on R studio Mac for read.table

Tags: r, macos, read.table, setwd

Sorry for the very basic question, but I have trouble importing a text file into R Studio on my mac.

I'm trying to do multiple linear regression on this set of data that looks like this:

```
HDL,TCC,SPB
47,287,0
38,236,0
47,255,0
......
```

When I use **file > import data set > from CSV**, the resulting column won't allow me to the the `lm()` function, or at least I don't know how to use it.

When I use `read.table(~/Desktop/HW.txt)`, it shows:

> ```
> Error: unexpected '/' in "read.table(~/"
> ```

When I use `read.table(/Users/yifeiwang/Desktop/HW2.txt)`, it shows:

> ```
> Error: unexpected '/' in "read.table(/"
> ```

How can I fix this or how can I import my text file in a matrix form?

Comment: You need to quote file path/names. If it really is a CSV file than also need to specifiy a sep parameter when using read.table: Perhaps: `dfrm <-
 read.table("~/Desktop/HW.txt", sep=",")`